# I'm not a brilliant mathematician

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

I'm not great at mathematics. Mental arithmetic I can do, but not algebra or calculus or anything like that... Anyway, here's a little puzzle I came up with in my spare time.

- I got where I am today due to more than 3<sup>14</sup> factors.
- I like to think I'm in my prime;
- in fact, I'm a prime example to many.
- I've got 20 digits, in all.
- My behaviour is generally natural...
- though sometimes I act a little irrationally. (Who doesn't?)
- The sum of my properties is in the millions;
- my primary product *does* have a high value.
- (Most of the time.)
- My function is complex, oft hated, but necessary.
- I mislike bubbles.

What am I?

---

#### Hint 1:

> My properties aren't mine.

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is

> Leo Varadkar

I got where I am today due to more than $3^{14}$ factors.

> $3^{14}$ is slightly less than the population of Ireland.

I like to think I'm in my prime;

> Mr Varadkar is the current Taoiseach (Prime Minister) of Ireland. He is also Ireland's youngest Taoiseach (so literally in his prime)

in fact, I'm a prime example to many.

> He is the first openly gay head of government for Ireland and was vocal during the same-sex marriage referendum in the country.

I've got 20 digits, in all.

> Ten fingers and ten toes

My behaviour is generally natural...

> He behaves generally as a politician should

though sometimes I act a little irrationally. (Who doesn't?)

> Not everyone will completely agree with the decisions he makes as leader.

The sum of my properties is in the millions;

> I think this refers to personal and professional residences which, if [Steward's Lodge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steward%27s_Lodge) is counted, would certainly have a total value in the millions.

my primary product does have a high value.

> Ireland's primary export is pharamaceuticals which generally have a high value

(Most of the time.)

> Obviously, the value of particular products can depend on demand and quality.

My function is complex, oft hated, but necessary.

> The head of state is often disliked and the role is a complex one to navigate but necessary in a democratic republic.

I mislike bubbles.

> The burst of the [Irish property bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_property_bubble) was a major contributor to the economic crisis in Ireland. Mr. Varadkar has also spoken about the dangers of a [land bubble](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/politics/no-evidence-of-a-land-bubble-in-ireland-says-varadkar-1.3583444) in Ireland.

Comment: You're closer than I thought would be possible; many of the answers to the clues are completely correct! But this isn't the answer I was thinking of. (Hint: what do most of your answers have in common, other than those that _directly_ pertain to the function of your answer?)

Comment: There's a hint now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Pi?

Reason:

> Pi is irrational, and therefore contains all natural numbers, prime numbers, etc  due to its infinite length.
>  "I've got 20 digits, in all" I took to again mean that all numbers are in it, kinda reversing the statement...
>  These clues could point to any irrational number, but the $3^{14}$ clue links to Pi's approximation of 3.14 and if you have bubbles in your pie you've either used the wrong ingredients or forgotten to prick/blind bake your pastry... :P

Comment: No, this isn't it. Your interpretations of both bullet points 2 _and_ 4 are "reversed", and I don't see how this fits bullet points 6, 9, 11 or 12.